# How to reload table after adding item on iOS app with Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, list, firebase

I have a view with a list of items with an Add button leading to another view in which you can add new items. The problem is what happens after you add the item. The new item appears correctly in the Firebase database but is not visible when you return to the list. I'm a little confused because I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am loading data again in the overrided functions such as vievDidLoad and vievWillAppear, but to be honest, new items do not appear until the application is closed and restarted.There is my code of my list:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var listOfItemsTableView: UITableView!

    var elements: [Element] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("recipes").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).getDocuments() { (snapshot, err) in
            if let snapshot = snapshot {
                for doc in snapshot.documents {
                    if let itemName = doc.get("name") as? String {
                        self.elements.append(Element(name: itemName))
                    }
                }
                self.listOfItemsTableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                if let err = err {
                    print(err)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.listOfItemsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return elements.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "elementCell", for: indexPath) as! ElementCell

        cell.elementNameLabel.text = elements[indexPath.row].name

        return cell
    }

    @IBAction func addItemButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toAddItemView", sender: self)
    }

}

class Element {
    var name = ""

    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you're using `getDocuments`, which is a one-time get of the query. What you want are realtime updates of the query, which requires adding a snapshot listener.

```
var elements = [Element]()

db.collection("recipes").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
    if let snapshot = snapshot {
        var elementsTemp = [Element]()
        for doc in snapshot.documents {
            if let itemName = doc.get("name") as? String {
                elementsTemp.append(Element(name: itemName))
            }
        }
        self.elements = elementsTemp
        self.listOfItemsTableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
})
```

You'll want to populate a temporary array inside the return and then hand that off to the datasourced array because updating the datasourced array incrementally (first removing all of its elements and then reconstructing it one element at a time) while the user may be scrolling is very prone to throwing an out-of-bounds error.

Comment: @Xavn77 Hold up a sec. The intention of this answer is correct, however the results are not going to be what you want. For example, with the provided code any changes in the observed collection will cause the code to fire, which will add the changed documents to the array - in addition to what's already there. Suppose a document is removed - that document will be passed to the closure and then it will be *added* to the elementsTemp array, which is not what you want. See [view changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots).

Comment: @Jay what you've explained is only for dealing with the `documentChanges` property of the snapshot. Firestore doesn't include deleted or duplicate documents in the `documents` property of the snapshot—`documents` is a clean snapshot of the current state of the query. Only if you want a diffable alternative to my answer would you use the `documentChanges` property, which for this use case is probably just matter of preference.

Comment: Maybe we're saying the same thing but .addSnapshotListener is passed a diff.type of .removed when a document is removed so then the removed documents can be investigated with `diff.document.data())` which is why this `print("Removed city: \(diff.document.data())")` would print the city that was removed. See the doc I linked above.

Comment: @Jay it’s also passed a clean snapshot that doesn’t include deleted or duplicate documents. It’s up to you whether you want to go the diffable route or the clean snapshot route.

Comment: Oops - I overlooked you are completely overwriting the entire array every time there's a single change to the database `self.elements = elementsTemp`. The point I was attempting to make was that the OP is working with a tableView. If the user swipes to delete a row there would generally be an animation of that row to indicate it was deleted - by totally reloading the entire array, and reloading the entire tableView that animation won't occur (well, it could). Whereas if the user knows which row is removed, it can be removed from Firestore and the array and the animation would occur as usual.

Comment: @Xavn77 definitely look at Jay's diffable mention if your list has swipe-to-delete or if you want finer control over animating differences in the UI.